center text on textwidth in a column of a table
Straight away here is my MWE
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}

\usepackage{array}

\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}

\begin{document}

\pagenumbering{gobble}

\newcolumntype{C}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{0.95\textwidth}}

\begin{center}
The \textsf{Long Entry} in the table should be centered on the total textwidth\\[12pt]
This is the center
\end{center}

\hrule

\vspace{12pt}

\begin{tabular}{|@{}l@{}|@{}C@{}|}
\makebox[0.05\textwidth]{123}  & \textsf{Long Long Long Long Long Long Long Long Long Long Long Long Long Long Entry}
\end{tabular}

\end{document}

What I want is the centering of the second column of the table to be aligned with the text width, but still leaving space for the first column.
The alignment can be achieved by setting the 0\textwidth in \makebox and p{1\textwidth} in tabular, but then the text overlap.
Seems tricky to do.

If you want to centre on the page and leave space on the left you need to leave the same space on the right

\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}

\usepackage{tabularx}

\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}

\begin{document}

\pagenumbering{gobble}

\newcolumntype{C}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}

\begin{center}
The \textsf{Long Entry} in the table should be centered on the total textwidth\\[12pt]
This is the center
\end{center}

\hrule

\vspace{12pt}

\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{}|wl{.05\textwidth}|C|wl{.05\textwidth}@{}}
123  & \textsf{Long Long Long Long Long Long Long Long Long Long Long Long Long Long Entry}& 
\end{tabularx}


or maybe


\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{}|wl{.05\textwidth}|Cwl{.05\textwidth}|@{}}
123  & \textsf{Long Long Long Long Long Long Long Long Long Long Long Long Long Long Entry}& 
\end{tabularx}

\end{document}


Brilliant as always, David.
